# Change maxConcurrentCalls setting for existing Resilience4j Bulkhead

Tags: resilience4j, bulkhead

Is it possible to change the maxConcurrentCalls setting for an already instantiated Resilience4j bulkhead?  I'd rather not create a new bulkhead with a new setting because then there would be a period where two bulkheads would be used and the number of concurrent calls would not be predictable.